# JasperReports editable pdf fields

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I've read in JasperReports Library 6.12.2 Change Log

- added support for PDF forms into the core library using custom properties at report element level
  to convert the report elements into editable text fields, lists, check boxes or radio groups when
  the report is exported to PDF format;

Can somebody help and describe how to use this possibilty?
I tried to set for textfield

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.text.isInputForm" value="true"/>
```

but it does not work.
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [JasperReports PDF forms sample documentation](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/forms/index.html).

Individual properties are also documented in the [JasperReports Configuration Reference](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.field.type).